# How to set background color dynamically/ pragmatically in android kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Dynamically change Button background in Kotlin Android. Below is my code. Is any other ways to do this in Kotlin ? Please suggest..

```
var btnBackground = findViewById(R.id.buttonBg) as Button
    var bgColor: Int = 1
    btnBackground.setOnClickListener { v ->
        if (bgColor == 1) {
            btnBackground.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_center_gradient)
            bgColor = 2
        } else if (bgColor == 2) {
            btnBackground.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_edge_color)
            bgColor = 3
        } else if (bgColor == 3) {
            btnBackground.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_gradient)
            bgColor=4
        }else if(bgColor==4){
            btnBackground.background=resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_solid_color)
            bgColor=1
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like all those `if` statements (one for each drawable background) then try something like this:

```
var btnBackground = findViewById(R.id.buttonBg) as Button
var bgColor: Int = 0
val bgDrawableIds = intArrayOf(
    R.drawable.btn_center_gradient,
    R.drawable.btn_edge_color,
    R.drawable.btn_gradient,
    R.drawable.btn_solid_color
)

btnBackground.setOnClickListener { v ->
    bgColor++
    btnBackground.background = resources.getDrawable(bgDrawableIds[bgColor % bgDrawableIds.size])
}
```

If you need to add more backgrounds, just add it to the array.